# Return value from WITH clause in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, cte

I am attempting to RETURN an integer from a plpgsql MERGE-related action that uses WITH. The value I want to RETURN is within the WITH statement below - the id. The error I receive with the below code is as follows:

> relation "post_insert" does not exist"

Explaining the code: This code might not be the most efficient way to do the below, but I am setting things up to work for some future use cases where I think I will need to use other features of MERGE. All this does is create a post through Post_Insert, and then using that Post_Insert (which returns the post's id), I create rows in the Hashtags_Posts table that relate back to a master hashtags table.

The "RETURN (SELECT id FROM Post_Insert)" is what is causing the problem. I cannot seem to get the id from Post_Insert and return it.

Any help on how to access the id in Post_Insert would be greatly appreciated.

```
  create or replace function createPost(
  uid_query text, 
  post_text_query text default '', 
  text_url_query text default '', 
  photo_url_query text default '', 
  video_url_query text default '', 
  audio_url_query text default '',
  location_query text default '',
  tags_array_query text[] default '{general}',  
  photo_query boolean default false
  )
returns integer language plpgsql as $$

BEGIN

WITH 
Post_Insert AS (
  INSERT INTO "Posts" (
    author, 
    post_text, 
    text_url, 
    photo_url, 
    video_url, 
    audio_url, 
    location,
    photo
  )
  VALUES (
    uid_query, 
    post_text_query, 
    text_url_query, 
    photo_url_query, 
    video_url_query, 
    audio_url_query,
    location_query,
    photo_query
  )
  RETURNING id
)

MERGE INTO "Hashtags_Posts" HP 
USING (SELECT * 
        FROM "Hashtags" H
        WHERE  H.hashtag = ANY(tags_array_query))
        as TMT
ON HP.id = (SELECT id FROM Post_Insert) AND TMT.id = HP.hashtag_id
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN  INSERT (post_id, hashtag_id)
        VALUES ((SELECT id FROM Post_Insert), TMT.id);

RETURN (SELECT id FROM Post_Insert);
END 
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why `INSERT` and `MERGE` would have to be in the same statement. (The whole function runs within the same transaction in any case.) Just split them up, and save the resulting `id` in a PL/pgSQL variable like [instructed in the manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW).

Or, better yet, use an [`OUT` parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) instead of a variable to simplify things:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_post(
     uid_query         text
   , post_text_query   text default '' 
   , text_url_query    text default '' 
   , photo_url_query   text default '' 
   , video_url_query   text default '' 
   , audio_url_query   text default ''
   , location_query    text default ''
   , tags_array_query  text[] default '{general}'  
   , photo_query       bool default false
   , OUT post_insert_id int                   -- use your actual data type!
   )
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO "Posts"
          (author   , post_text      , text_url      , photo_url      , video_url      , audio_url      , location      , photo)
   VALUES (uid_query, post_text_query, text_url_query, photo_url_query, video_url_query, audio_url_query, location_query, photo_query)
   RETURNING id
   INTO post_insert_id;

   MERGE INTO "Hashtags_Posts" hp
   USING (SELECT * 
          FROM   "Hashtags" h
          WHERE  h.hashtag = ANY(tags_array_query)) tmt
             ON hp.id = post_insert_id
            AND tmt.id = hp.hashtag_id
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (post_id, hashtag_id)
      VALUES (post_insert_id, tmt.id);

   -- no separate RETURN needed, post_insert_id is declared OUT param
END 
$func$;
```

And my standing advice is to use legal, lower-case identifiers in Postgres, which can't be messed up by (missing) double-quotes. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)